# Launch a program when X starts

Tags: xorg, lightdm

I want to launch a program when **X** (not unity/gnome/etc) starts.

In particular, I want to launch `xset r 105` when `lightdm` starts. Is there a way to do it? I tried writing this into `~/.xsessionrc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
xset r 105
```

but it didn't nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change one of these settings in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:

```
# session-wrapper = Wrapper script to run session with
# display-setup-script = Script to run when starting a greeter session (runs as root)
# greeter-setup-script = Script to run when starting a greeter (runs as root)
# session-setup-script = Script to run when starting a user session (runs as root)
```

I think that **display-setup-script** is what you want to modify. Just set it to your script. Turn that xset command into an executable shell script and stick it into /usr/bin. Then the config file will be:

```
display-setup-script=/usr/bin/xset_script.sh
```

Comment: excellent, exactly what I was searching for. Many thanks!